# Async function call from mfc object using lambda callback

Tags: c++, mfc

I keep hearing from SO - no GUI work from worker thread. I understand the following async function could however be executed from a mfc class using a PostMessage(), but I
am still tempted to rather use a callback lambda function.I want to know the downside of this, if any.

```
std::future<void> refresh(std:: function<void()> win_func)
 {
     std::async(std::launch::async,[&]()
          {
               // do long process

              win_func();
           });
 }

void CWinDlg::OnClick()
{
     refresh( [&]()
         {
             // want to avoid PostMessage() here
            // sync with mfc required here?

            clist_ctrl1.Update();
         });
}
```

Comment: You would have to implement synchronization anyway in this case, as `CListCtrl::Update()` takes an item index. The item index must be valid and refer to the desired item at the time of call, and the only way to ensure this is to synchronize access. You'd run into the same problems when posting a message. The underlying problem here is, that you are potentially updating the same control from different threads, potentially interspersing the updates. This is nothing you can easily prevent, since there is a user potentially interacting with the control through the owning thread.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks for the precise response but your last sentence need little elaboration for me. Since I can also lock the control during the busy state, whether this would suffice for the index to be still valid ?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to lock the control to prevent updates. And if there was, there wouldn't be much benefit in offloading the updates to a worker thread.

Comment: I am using a virtual listctrl as I will be loading huge database records to a vector , to be displayed through the listctrl which kind of becomes sluggish during refresh, else GUI will become irresponsive.

Comment: Sounds like you are using the virtual list control in a way it's not meant to be used. A refresh essentially consists of setting the number of items, where each item then uses a callback to retrieve the information for display from a pool of data, potentially updated on a worker thread. You don't update the entire list view in one batch operation. Instead, you generate the display information when those items are scrolled into view.

Comment: If I query database for every scroll position, the display shows glitches (not smooth).I have tried that way too

Comment: The MSDN topic [Virtual List Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye4z8x58.aspx) explains how to use virtual list controls.

Comment: That's not how virtual list controls work. If you must, you can *trigger* a DB query on each scroll, fill the visible rows with placeholder text (e.g. `Loading...`), run the query on a worker thread, and have it post a message to the UI thread. The UI thread can then invalidate the list control to trigger a repaint, and display those items that are now available.